# Did Vader intend to eventually bring Padme back to life?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

With regards to Anakin's vision of Padme's death, and how Palpatine's offer can lure him, I saw this comment in another question:

> He believed that even if Padme did die, he could use the Dark Side to bring her back. So ultimately, he wanted a little Zombie Padme action.

When he finally turned to the dark side, Sidious promised that together they will rediscover the secret to bring the dead back to life.

Considering that the eventuality of Padme being dead did come to pass, then does Vader still intend to bring her back in the years since, on the off chance that the secret of Darth Plagueis is successfully rediscovered?

**Edit**: This is not a duplicate. The other question asks if the Sith ever rediscovered Darth Plagueis' secret of bringing one back from death. This question isn't asking if the secret was rediscovered, it's asking if Vader still plans to do what he originally wanted to do with that power once he learns to use it. (Not to mention that question's answers are all Legends)

My question, however, is asking about Darth Vader's original MOTIVE for joining the dark side. Vader joined the dark side so that, in the event Padme dies, he can bring her back to life. Turns out, she really died, but then he needs to first rediscover the secret to bringing one back from the dead before he can use it on Padme.

So, FROM VADER'S PERSPECTIVE, does he still intend to bring Padme back to life - which is why he joined the dark side in the first place - in the event the secret is indeed rediscovered, for the rest of his life spent as a Sith?

Comment: This should be reopened. The questions are manifestly different (intent to bring Padme back, vs. success in cheating death overall), and Vader is barely mentioned in the answers to the other question, so we can't really tell what his plans were.

Comment: The question is different but the answer is the same. Since Palpatine only succeeded by cloning himself, he didn't really find how to bring people back. Furthermore, the premise of the question is false. _When he finally turned to the dark side, Sidious promised that together they will rediscover the secret to bring the dead back to life._ No, Sidious said he was confident that with their power combined, they could re discover the secret of immortality, not how to bring back people. That's two different things. I think this should stay closed. I'm open to engage a discussion in meta though.

Comment: The answer's not the same. "Palpatine found a way, but it can't be used to save Padme" doesn't answer "all these years, does Vader still intend to bring dead Padme back?" Before Palpatine's discovery, it's a valid question. The other question's answer stated Palpatine's way was different from Plagueis' way ("able to save the ones he loved, but not himself"). Vader has reason to believe Plagueis way - which is yet to be found - can bring Padme back, so after the discovery, the question still stands: Does he still plan to bring Padme back after all these years, if the way is indeed found?

Comment: Additionally, I directly quote the lines from the movie. Vader: "Just help me save Padme's life, I can't live without her." Sidious: "To cheat death is a power only one has achieved. But if we work together, I know we can discover the secret." It didn't say this is a self-casting spell that cannot be used to target other corpses - nothing was mentioned on the subject. But we know it's different from Palpatine's method (which is self-cast only), and Plagueis' experiments on Venamis had successfully brought the latter back from the dead multiple times - does Vader still want to use it on Padme?